# What happens when True Polymorph is cast on a "creature" created by Polymorph Any Object?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Say I were to polymorph a table into say a goblin with Polymorph any object. Directly afterwards I used polymorph true on this table goblin. Firstly does this work? Second does the new thing count as a creature? Can said thing be resurrected once slain?

This question inspired mine.
[Can an object that's changed into a creature that then dies be brought back to life?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87616/can-an-object-thats-changed-into-a-creature-that-then-dies-be-brought-back-to-l/87620?noredirect=1#comment198780_87620)

Comment: Which book contains True Polymorph? Or is the question regarding PAO vs the 4th level *polymorph*?

Answer (score 1):

The effects of spells of the same subschool (In this case, Polymorph) Typically don't stack. So it's unlikely that casting Polymorph Any Object would do anything but overwrite True Polymorph. This falls under this [stacking clause in the PHB](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm):

> **One Effect Makes Another Irrelevant**
>
> Sometimes, one spell can render a later spell irrelevant. Both spells are still active, but one has rendered the other useless in some fashion.

When the creature dies, any spell of the Polymorph Subschool durates and it unconditionally returns to its original form, which would be a table.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only that Googled that. "Surely that can't be a real word." In fact, it seems that it is not.

Comment: @HeyICanChan You, not being Martin Luther, *should not of* opened that can of Würms.

Comment: Durate means the time when an effect's duration elapses.